# Why getting invalid literal when running this script?

Tags: python, dictionary, error-handling

When I run the following script, I get ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2-' when the date only contains 1 digit (ie 02-02-2011). However it works fine when the date has 2 digits (ie 11-11-2011). What is the reason for this, and how can I fix it?

```
from __future__ import division
from easygui import *
import ystockquote
import datetime
import math

def main():
    stock = 'NFLX'
    name = ystockquote.get_company_name(stock)
    start_date = create_date(02,13,2009)
    end_date = create_date(10,21,2014)
    start_price = get_price_on_date(stock,start_date)
    end_price = get_price_on_date(stock,end_date)
    if not isinstance(start_price,str):
        print "Please enter a different start date, the market was closed on the day you chose!"
        quit()
    else:
        start_price = float(start_price)
    if not isinstance(end_price,str):
        print "Please enter a different end date, the market was closed on the day you chose!"
        quit()
    else:
        end_price = float(end_price)
    no_of_shares = math.floor(10000/float(start_price))
    profit = (end_price-start_price)*no_of_shares
    print "The profit resulting from investing $10,000 in " + name + " from " + start_date + " to " + end_date + " would have been " + "$" + str(profit) + " or a return of {:.2%}".format(profit/10000) + " ."

def get_price_on_date(stock,date):
    a = ystockquote.get_historical_prices(stock,date,date)
    for key, value in a.iteritems() :
        for key, value in value.iteritems() :
            if key == 'Close':
               return value

def create_date(month,day,year):
    date_string = str(year) + "-" + str(month) + "-" + str(day)
    return date_string

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: because you dont know how to `str.split("-")` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `create_date()` function is not returning two-digit day and month numbers in all cases.

Try formatting the values explicitly instead of using `str()`:

```
date_string = "{0:04}-{1:02}-{2:02}".format(year, month, day)
```